# Swagger does not work when Application startup file is placed inside a package. Kotlin Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger, openjdk-11

My project directory structure is like following

```
└── activity
    ├── app
    │   └── ActivityApplication.kt
    ├── controller
    │   └── WelcomeMessageController.kt
    ├── exception
    │   ├── ActivityErrorResponse.kt
    │   ├── handler
    │   │   └── ActivityServiceExceptionHandler.kt
    │   └── response
    │       └── ResponseCode.kt
    ├── model
    │   └── WelcomeMessage.kt
    ├── repository
    │   └── WelcomeMessageRepository.kt
    ├── service
    │   └── WelcomeService.kt
    └── swagger
        └── SwaggerConfig.kt
```

When I move my `ActivityApplication.kt` file to root package i.e. directly under `activity` swagger page starts to work normally. However, when i move it inside a package (in this case `app`) then swagger page does not show anything but following error

***Error:*** *Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:*

my swagger config looks like following

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .pathProvider(object: RelativePathProvider(null) {
                    override fun getApplicationBasePath(): String {
                        return "/activity"
                    }
                })
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.activity.controller"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(buildApiInfo())
    }

    private fun buildApiInfo(): ApiInfo? {
        return ApiInfo(
                ...)
    }
}
```

`ActivityApplication.kt` has only following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
class ActivityApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ActivityApplication>(*args)
}
```

- **Java Version**: OpenJDK 11
- **Springfox-swagger2 version**: 2.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot tries to find it's components in deeper packages. I.e. if you place `@SpringBootApplication` on `activity.app.ActivityApplication`, Spring Boot will only search under `activity.app` and won't go to `activity.swagger`, on any other packages.

If you don't want to move you `ActivityApplication` to `activity` package, then you need to manually specify base packages in `@SpringBootApplication` annotation's `scanBasePackages` parameter: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "activity")`.

**Note:** it should be full package, e.g. `mycompany.myproject.activity`).